# PHP function missing bracket? Crashes page

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce in Wordpress and am trying to add two pieces of code from their documentation to my functions.php file

See [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/change-add-to-cart-button-text/) for the two pieces of code I want to add.

I added the first to my file and it worked great. But add the second one and the entire site smashes, I assume because the functions.php file is so vital and there is a syntax error... but I can't spot it, and this documentation comes from their site!

This is what I have added:

```
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );
    function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
                return __( 'Add to basket', 'woocommerce' );

        }

add_filter('single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text');
    function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
                return __('Add to basket', 'woocommerce');
        }
```

You can see the full file [here](http://pastebin.com/qxMUB6G7) to see them in context, starts from line 61.

Can anybody see why adding these two functions might be causing the entire site to smash? It seems weird that adding just one is fine but add two and it breaks the file.

Comment: You can not redeclare a function, that is already there. Choose a different Name for the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not where the error is coming from, but I think you added the same function twice:

```
function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
    return __('Add to basket', 'woocommerce');
}
```

You're probably getting a *fatal* `Cannot redeclare function` error which causes your script to halt.

Comment: The problem is I change it, I then have to go through every single file that uses it to change it too, and that makes it impossible to run Woocommerce updates. This is their code, so it should work?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is so because you are creating two functions with the same name (you are re-declaring the first one). Try using a different function name for the second one.